# Discrete version of student-t distribution

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

Does anyone know of a good source for the study of the discrete version of Student t distribution? J K Ord seems to have studied it in his PhD thesis. However, I couldn't get an access to it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "the" discrete version of the Student t distribution? In what sense is any discrete distribution "Student-t"-like? [It is the case that Keith Ord wrote about discrete distributions in his PhD thesis; I haven't seen it though]

Comment: over-dispersed binomial? I can imagine only this context.

Comment: @German I think it's better if we don't speculate about what the OP intends. Perhaps there's some specific thing that the OP has read or some specific thing to try to achieve that will guide us to a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you. What I mean by discrete version of Student-t is that the expression of the pdf is the same but the support is discrete (and finite).

Comment: got it. I only found I guess the same that you also found https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177698133 :/

Comment: and 1 mention there: https://books.google.es/books?id=JchiadWLnykC&pg=PA498&lpg=PA498&dq=student+t+distribution+discrete+ord&source=bl&ots=pYyI6cBxqo&sig=7o6hZ-A7lC01g7ejeeIX0CgpRBI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi83ZL99eXWAhWE0RQKHW-DCpEQ6AEITzAF#v=onepage&q=student%20t%20distribution%20discrete%20ord&f=false

Comment: Ashiok -- looking at the paper, the specific sense in which it's a discrete analog of a Pearson type VII (i.e. a t-distribution) is that one takes the differential equation from which Pearson obtained the Pearson family of distributions and replaces it with a *difference equation*. There's a region with a ratio of quadratic forms with imaginary roots (equivalent to the type IV), and it has a special case, in turn corresponding to type VII in the Pearson scheme, that Ord is discussing in the paper German linked. (I was trying to get his 1967 Biometrika paper but I'm having trouble getting it)

Comment: It's a very interesting case -- although the odd moments are 0 (when they exist), the distribution is only symmetric for a few special cases.

Comment: It's here https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2335056.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:9730f7349badc663ae552686de91d457 Thank you for discussion.